# Create token with card after payment transaction

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

Hello I am new to flutter and Stripe and I have this issue about creating cards. To start, the user must have a stored CreditCard so I used StripePayment.createTokenWithCard and send the output tokenID to the server-side API to create the Credit Card, and it was successfully done. Then next is another feature where the user has to pay via Stripe. I have to use StripePayment.setStripeAccount(stripe_connect_account_id) so that processing the paymentIntents and all to be successful, it was also successful. Here comes the issue, after a successful transaction whenever the user wants to create new card and go back to the screen where I used StripePayment.createTokenWithCard and send the output to the server-side API, the API would give me an http status 400-{"error":"No such token: 'tok_1INxXpBd3AiaZE5efApj6I2D'"}, but if I restart the app manually it will be successful.

What will I do with this? Is there a way for me not to restart the app as it is not user friendly. How to unset Stripe Account and get back to normal before transaction begins?

Comment: If you get a "No such token" error it usually means you are using Connect and not using Stripe-Account correctly(https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication) so I'd carefully check your backend code and see if you need to pass it there, or if you're passing it when you don't need it. You also might simply have a mix up in your API keys.

Comment: @karllekko Is there a way I can undo/remove StripePayment.setStripeAccount(stripe_connect_account_id) in flutter?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used that library. It looks like a global variable though so it seems unlikely you can change it without re-initialising that library somehow. In Stripe's official libraries there are ways to set Stripe-Account on a per-call basis(for example you can initialise multiple STPAPIClients(https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAPIClient.html) and use them for different calls) but I don't know how/if you do that in that Flutter library.